# Encrypted email validation in laravel

Tags: laravel

In laravel Authtication Process I want to encrypt the email field in the users table(I have used Crypt::encrypt()). On doing so, the Login process fails. I have to validate encrypted email when login. Can someone help me out?

Comment: why are you encrypt email?

Comment: @EtibarRustemzade It is not bad to encrypt the user's private information. I would even encourage that. (Altough I never do it myself)

Comment: Just try to `encrypt` the specific input data on the login process and authenticate with this encrypted input data.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think iterating over database data is scalable. In my case, I'm also encrypting other fields from other entities, so in that regard my answer is based on [@Eskaaa's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54811560/3025856).

I created a [command](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/artisan#writing-commands) that prints an IV and added the value printed by the command in a property called `APP_IV` to my `.env`:

```
public function handle()
{
    echo base64_encode(random_bytes(openssl_cipher_iv_length($this->laravel['config']['app.cipher'])));
    return Command::SUCCESS;
}
```

Then, I added the line below to my `config/app.php`:

```
'iv' => env('APP_IV'),
```

Now, I have created the `MyCustomEncrypter` class which inherits from the `Illuminate\Encryption\Encrypter` class. `Encrypter` is responsible for implementing Laravel's **encrypt** and **decrypt**. I needed to override the encrypt method and load the IV in the constructor.

```
class MyCustomEncrypter extends Encrypter
{
    private $iv;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->iv = base64_decode(config('app.iv'));
        $key = base64_decode(Str::after(config('app.key'), 'base64:'));

        parent::__construct($key, config('app.cipher'));
    }

    public function encrypt($value, $serialize = true)
    {
        $iv = $this->iv;

        $value = \openssl_encrypt(
            $serialize ? serialize($value) : $value,
            $this->cipher, $this->key, 0, $iv
        );

        if ($value === false) {
            throw new EncryptException('Could not encrypt the data.');
        }

        $mac = $this->hash($iv = base64_encode($iv), $value);

        $json = json_encode(compact('iv', 'value', 'mac'), JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);

        if (json_last_error() !== JSON_ERROR_NONE) {
            throw new EncryptException('Could not encrypt the data.');
        }

        return base64_encode($json);
    }
}
```

To encrypt the data, I created a custom [Cast](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators#custom-casts), and set the attributes that would be encrypted in the models:

```
class EncrypterCast implements CastsAttributes
{
    private $myEncrypter;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->myEncrypter = new MyCustomEncrypter;
    }

    public function get($model, string $key, $value, array $attributes)
    {
        return $this->myEncrypter->decryptString($value);
    }

    public function set($model, string $key, $value, array $attributes)
    {
        return $this->myEncrypter->encryptString($value);
    }
}
```

User Model:

```
class User extends Authenticatable implements MustVerifyEmail
{
    ...

    protected $casts = [
        'name' => EncrypterCast::class,
        'email' => EncrypterCast::class,
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];

    ...
}
```

I used [Laravel Breeze](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/starter-kits#laravel-breeze) to generate the login, login verification, and password recovery screens. All of the steps to follow are based on the **Laravel Breeze** code.

#### Login

I needed to modify the `authenticate` method of the `App\Http\Requests\Auth\LoginRequest` class. This ended up as:

```
public function authenticate()
{
    $this->ensureIsNotRateLimited();
    
    $credentials = $this->only('email', 'password');

    if (array_key_exists('email', $credentials)) {
        $encrypter = new MyCustomEncrypter;
        $credentials['email'] = $encrypter->encryptString($credentials['email']);
    }

    if (! Auth::attempt($credentials, $this->boolean('remember'))) {
        RateLimiter::hit($this->throttleKey());

        throw ValidationException::withMessages([
            'email' => __('auth.failed'),
        ]);
    }

    RateLimiter::clear($this->throttleKey());
}
```

#### Login Verification

No changes were needed, as Laravel uses the `User::email` attribute; Cast itself decrypts the data.

#### Password Recovery

I didn't encrypt the email in the password recovery table; it would take a lot of work to do so, and whenever the token is used it clears the registry in the base. Given this, I only needed to change two methods. The `store` method of the `App\Http\Controllers\Auth\PasswordResetLinkController` class and the `store` method of the `App\Http\Controllers\Auth\NewPasswordController` class.

#### `PasswordResetLinkController.php`

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate([
        'email' => ['required', 'email'],
    ]);

    $credentials = $request->only('email');

    if (array_key_exists('email', $credentials)) {
        $encrypter = new MyCustomEncrypter;
        $credentials['email'] = $encrypter->encryptString($credentials['email']);
    }

    $status = Password::sendResetLink($credentials );

    return $status == Password::RESET_LINK_SENT
                ? back()->with('status', __($status))
                : back()->withInput($request->only('email'))
                        ->withErrors(['email' => __($status)]);
}
```

#### `NewPasswordController.php`

```
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'token' => ['required'],
            'email' => ['required', 'email'],
            'password' => ['required', 'confirmed', Rules\Password::defaults()],
        ]);

        $credentials = $request->only('email', 'password', 'password_confirmation', 'token');

        if (array_key_exists('email', $credentials)) {
            $encrypter = new MyCustomEncrypter;
            $credentials['email'] = $encrypter->encryptString($credentials['email']);
        }
        
        $status = Password::reset(
            $credentials,
            function ($user) use ($request) {
                $user->forceFill([
                    'password' => Hash::make($request->password),
                    'remember_token' => Str::random(60),
                ])->save();

                event(new PasswordReset($user));
            }
        );

        return $status == Password::PASSWORD_RESET
                    ? redirect()->route('login')->with('status', __($status))
                    : back()->withInput($request->only('email'))
                            ->withErrors(['email' => __($status)]);
    }
}
```

Done! My version of Laravel is 8.x

Answer (score 1):

if i did understand your problem well, a good way to resolve it is using the decorator pattern! and since Laravel provides a way to create **middlewares** easily, we can use them as decorators.

what you need to do is to add a **middleware** named  *encryptEmails* and as we know, a middleware can have access to the request object! what we need to do now is to retrieve the email value from the request and change it by encrypting it.

of course you must include this middleware on your login route.

using this approach, you won't need to change the content of the built-in authentication class.

here is a code of the middleware's **handle** function ( i am not sure about the class or the method that encrypts the email ) :

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    $request->email = Crypt::encrypt($request->email)
    return $next($request);
}
```

you can check this link to get more information about middlewares in Laravel : 
https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/middleware

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you should allow a user to log in by using a username. [Override the `username()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/authentication#included-authenticating) method in `LoginController`:

```
public function username()
{
    return 'username';
}
```

If you still want to use email for authentication, you'll need to load all the users and then check each user's decrypted email which is a bad idea if you have many users registered.

```
$users = User::all();
foreach ($users as $user) {
    if ($request->email === decrypt($user->email) && \Hash::check($request->password, $user->password)) {
        auth()->login($user); // Login the user if email and password are correct
        break; // Exit from the foreach loop
    }
}
```

You can also [chunk the data](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent#chunking-results).

Again, this solution is ok only for a small number of registered users.

Comment: Isn't the Laravel way using an [accessor](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor)?

Comment: @ThomasMoors of course, you should use an accessor instead of manually do `decrypt($user->email)`. It's a good practice to use accessors and mutators. But here I'm just answering the question and I'm trying to keep it simple.

Answer (score 0):

I have used the below code in `LoginController` and worked for me in Laravel 5.6,

```
public function attemptLogin(Request $request) {
    $users = User::all();
    $isUserValidated=false;
    $field = $request->username;
    foreach ($users as $user) {
        try { // required if the field is not encrypted
            // login using username or email
            if (($field === Crypt::decryptString($user->email) || $field === Crypt::decryptString($user->username)) && \Hash::check($request->password, $user->password)) {
                $isUserValidated=true;
                $this->guard()->login($user,false);
                break; // Exit from the foreach loop
            }
        } catch (DecryptException $e) {
            //
        }
    }
    return $isUserValidated;
}
```

Comment: What is the `Crypt` exactly doing behind the scenes?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's important to be able to encrypt the email for login. The problem with Laravel is that it always uses a different initialization vector.

To work around this problem, you can create two methods that use a fixed initialization vector. Then you do not have to loop through all users. You are able to compare the email from request with the database records.

The email must always be decrypted when reading from model. When saving, it must always be encrypted. If you use a unique rule and an email rule for validation, you have to do the validation of the user data in two steps. First the rule Email to validate the format, then Encrypt the passed email and then validate by rule unqiue.

I hope I have been able to help a little.

**Note: This is not a ready-made solution, just a code example as an idea. If you try this solution, you need to take care about the password broker and password reset.**

```php
/** 
  * Get a new initialization vector 
  * Store this initialization vector in your app-config (/config/app.php)
  **/
function getNewIv() :string
{
    return openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(16);
}

/** encrypt **/
function encryptEmail(string $email): string
{
    $cipher = config('app.cipher', 'AES-256-CBC');
    $key = config('app.key');
    $iv= config('app.iv');

    $encrypted = openssl_encrypt($email, $cipher, $key, 1, base64_decode($iv));
    return base64_encode($encrypted);
}


/** decrypt **/
function decryptEmail(string $email): string
{
    $data = base64_decode($decryptString);
    $cipher = config('app.cipher', 'AES-256-CBC');
    $key = config('app.key');
    $iv= config('app.iv');

    return openssl_decrypt($data, $cipher, $key, 1, base64_decode($iv));
}
```